# Does a boosting circuit reduce battery voltage without any load?

Tags: led, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, boost, lipo

Suppose I am trying to boost the voltage of my 3.7V Lipo battery to 8V using a boost converter (MT3608 module) and lighting up some LEDs.

Does the voltage of the battery reduce just because of the boosting circuit, if no load is connected at the output(which is 8V) of boost converter?

**Does the boosting module play a role in reducing the battery voltage when no load connected, or does the battery drain as usual in the same way with or without a boosting circuit when no load is connected?**

I'm doing it practically now. My lipo battery voltage is 3.7V, I boosted the voltage to 8V (without any load) and left it to check whether boosting circuit reduces the batery voltage. In 1 hour battery voltage has reduced to 3.67

What is the reason for this and how can I avoid this problem, since suppose say if we are trying to make a PCB, Lipo battery will always be connected to boosting circuit and it can drain the battery overnight.

[image: MT3608 circuit Diagram]

Comment: You will always have some leakage if anything is connected to the battery. The question would be more how much you can tolerate.

Comment: check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJJcdptSH80&feature=youtu.be&t=101

Comment: Do you see L1, D1, R2 and R1? Do you see how current always flows through that path even if the boost chip doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 2):

> Does boosting module play a role in reducing the battery voltage when no load connected?

What you're asking as called the **quiescent current consumption** of the boost converter.
This is the current that the boost converter takes when it outputs the boosted voltage ( 8 V) but **no current** is pulled (by the load) from that 8 V.

When I want to know this \$I_q\$ I look at the [datasheet](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf) of the chip, on page 3 there's a table with the information:

[image]

The Shutdown current is the lowest but then the converter is shut-down so there will not be 8 V at the output!

There are two Quiescent Current figures, one for PFM and one for PWM.

Usually PFM is used when the load uses a small current, the converter then operates in small bursts and shuts down in between bursts. This saves supply current as we can see in the numbers: \$I_{q,PFM}\$ = 100 uA typically

PWM is used when the load is higher. The converter switches continuously. The \$I_{q,PWM}\$ has a higher value (1.6 mA typically) compared to the PFM mode but that usually is not an issue as the load will draw a lot of current as well. So the 1.6 mA that the converter needs is usually small compared to the load current.

So yes, the converter will take some current, it will take around 100 uA continuously. If that will drain your battery overnight depends on the capacity of your battery. With a 1000 mAh battery, at 100 uA it takes 10 thousand hours to discharge, that's 400 days. My guess is that you will be using a battery with more capacity than 1000 mAh so I do not think the converter can drain your battery overnight.

The change from 3.7 V to 3.67 V doesn't mean much, that can be due to temperature changes as well. I would **measure** the actual quiescent current, and if it is more than 200 uA (the specified maximum) then I would investigate what's going on.

Comment: Im planning to use a 350mAh or 500mAh battery and boostup the voltage to 7or 8v, So that I can operate 4 LEDs ( 2 white LEDs in series, parallely connected with 2 Blue LEDs in series) with a DPDT switch, so that 2 Warm white will operate at one mode of switch and 2 Blue will operate at another mode. The reason Im gng for boosting circuit to lightup is, I dont want LEDs to get dim as the voltage reduces. So I have gone for boosting circuit where I get a constant voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from one voltage to another voltage is not done with 100% efficiency. Even without any load there will be some losses. So your options to look at are :

1. Get best efficiency possible for the load and/or no-load conditions, by reducing losses in components. This has limits...
2. You could disable conversion if the load does not need the voltage. This can be done with the enable/disable pin of the converter if there's one. And you could also completely disconnect the battery from the conversion circuit using a switch (transistor or whatever suits your application), again, with the same enable/disable signal.

There may be some others that not come to mind now, but in the end it's most likely you would use all of the above means to reduce any drain on the battery if it is unbearable.

Answer (score 0):

With no load on the 8 volt output of the MT3608 booster, the current consumption from the battery is about 1.6 mA. So, if you know the characteristic voltage discharge curve of your battery, you should be able to estimate how much the voltage drops in one hour. The numbers you give sound about right.

Comment: I think the MT3608  is "smart" and will use PFM when there's a light load (the datasheet claims that it does) so that \$I_q\$ = 100 uA.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you may indeed be right. I’ve never used the chip. However, the message is clear enough (I hope) and that is to understand the voltage-current drain characteristic of the battery in order to make a proper estimate.